# What is $y''$, where $y' = 1 - t + 4y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a brainfart while trying to solve a problem for differential equations that requires me to recall some Calculus. If I have $y' = f(t, y) = 1 - t + 4y$, what is $y''$? Do I just differentiate with respect to $t$ to get $y'' = -1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming $y'=\frac{dy}{dt}$ since there are no other variables here.

We have $\large \frac{dy}{dt} = 1 - t +4y$

Differentiating with respect to $t$ (your idea is right, but the final answer isn't)

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = -1+4\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Substituting back the original value of $\frac{dy}{dt}$

$$\begin{align}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} &= -1+4 - 4t +16y\\
&=3-4t+16y\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh, well this is awkward. I'm up even later than I was last night! You should be yelling at me, not helping me! Hehe

Comment: Another way of writing this is to eliminate $t$ instead of $y'$

Comment: @MarkBennet yes. it is. Or we could write entire expression in terms of $t$ as well. This just required the least calculation.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
y'' = \frac{d^2}{dt^2}y = \frac{d}{dt}y' = \frac{d}{dt} (1-t)  + 4\frac{d}{dt} y = -1 + 4y' = -1+4-4t+16y = 3 - 4t + 16y
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

One standard way of solving $$y'-4y=1-t$$

This is linear, so if $y=F(t)$ is a solution and $G(t)$ is any solution of the homogeneous equation: $$G'-4G=0$$ $y=F+G$ is also a solution.

The homogeneous equation is solved in various ways (e.g. separation of variables) as $G(t)=ae^{4t}$

For a particular solution, with a polynomial on the right-hand side, we try a polynomial $F(t)=ct+d$, $F'=c$ $$F'-4F=-4ct+c-4d$$ whence $c=\frac 14, d=-\frac 3{16}$.